# Symfony: How to create a POST request for one-to-many relationship with Voryx REST Bundle

Tags: rest, symfony, orm, crud

Given the following `Category` entity...

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category", uniqueConstraints = @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_categoryName", columns={"name"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=256, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Subcategory", mappedBy="category", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $subcategories;

    ...
}
```

... and the following `Subcategory` entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Subcategory
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="subcategory")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\SubcategoryRepository")
 */
class Subcategory
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=256, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="subcategories")
     */
    private $category;

    ...
}
```

I'm using https://github.com/voryx/restgeneratorbundle
 to generate the REST controllers... and here below is how my `src/AppBundle/Form/SubcategoryType` looks like (`src/AppBundle/Form/CategoryType` is very similar):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SucategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('category', 'voryx_entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category'))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Sucategory'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_subcategory';
    }
}
```

Finally here is my `src/AppBundle/Controller/CategoryRESTController`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Category;
use AppBundle\Form\CategoryType;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\QueryParam;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RouteResource;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
use FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcherInterface;
use FOS\RestBundle\Util\Codes;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View as FOSView;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Voryx\RESTGeneratorBundle\Controller\VoryxController;

/**
 * Category controller.
 * @RouteResource("Category")
 */
class CategoryRESTController extends VoryxController
{
    /**
     * Get a Category entity
     *
     * @View(serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)
     *
     * @return Response
     *
     */
    public function getAction(Category $entity)
    {
        return $entity;
    }

    /**
     * Get all Category entities.
     *
     * @View(serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)
     *
     * @param ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher
     *
     * @return Response
     *
     * @QueryParam(name="offset", requirements="\d+", nullable=true, description="Offset from which to start listing notes.")
     * @QueryParam(name="limit", requirements="\d+", default="20", description="How many notes to return.")
     * @QueryParam(name="order_by", nullable=true, array=true, description="Order by fields. Must be an array ie. &order_by[name]=ASC&order_by[description]=DESC")
     * @QueryParam(name="filters", nullable=true, array=true, description="Filter by fields. Must be an array ie. &filters[id]=3")
     */
    public function cgetAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
    {
        try {
            $offset = $paramFetcher->get('offset');
            $limit = $paramFetcher->get('limit');
            $order_by = $paramFetcher->get('order_by');
            $filters = !is_null($paramFetcher->get('filters')) ? $paramFetcher->get('filters') : array();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findBy($filters, $order_by, $limit, $offset);
            if ($entities) {
                return $entities;
            }

            return FOSView::create('Not Found', Codes::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return FOSView::create($e->getMessage(), Codes::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a Category entity.
     *
     * @View(statusCode=201, serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     *
     */
    public function postAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Category();
        $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryType(), $entity, array("method" => $request->getMethod()));
        $this->removeExtraFields($request, $form);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $entity;
        }

        return FOSView::create(array('errors' => $form->getErrors()), Codes::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    /**
     * Update a Category entity.
     *
     * @View(serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $entity
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function putAction(Request $request, Category $entity)
    {
        try {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $request->setMethod('PATCH'); //Treat all PUTs as PATCH
            $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryType(), $entity, array("method" => $request->getMethod()));
            $this->removeExtraFields($request, $form);
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em->flush();

                return $entity;
            }

            return FOSView::create(array('errors' => $form->getErrors()), Codes::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return FOSView::create($e->getMessage(), Codes::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Partial Update to a Category entity.
     *
     * @View(serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $entity
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function patchAction(Request $request, Category $entity)
    {
        return $this->putAction($request, $entity);
    }

    /**
     * Delete a Category entity.
     *
     * @View(statusCode=204)
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $entity
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Category $entity)
    {
        try {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return null;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return FOSView::create($e->getMessage(), Codes::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Posting a request to add a single category like this works perfectly:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name" : "Sport", "description" : "Sport category"}' http://localhost:8000/api/categories
```

... and here is the result:

```
+----+-------+---------------------------+
| id | name  | description               |
+----+-------+---------------------------+
|  1 | Sport | Sport category            |
+----+-------+---------------------------+
```

But how do I post a request to add a subcategory to the category created above? The idea would be to add a subcategory like this:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name" : "Football", "description" : "Groups ranks about football"}' http://localhost:8000/api/categories/1/subcategories
```

Comment: Is your question solved by my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, creating POST request for category subcategories resources will be perfectly ok.

I also think (based on this how your entities looks) that You don't need `SubcategoryType`. As it will be this same as `CategoryType`.

Instead two entities you can take a look at `Gedmo Tree extension`: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md and keep all of it on one entity.